# The qtoctave package was removed from Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf official repositories?

Tags: package-management, 15.10, octave

There is no more qtoctave in Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf?

I've tried to install and obtained this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qtoctave
E: Package 'qtoctave' has no installation candidate
```

Searching in http://packages.ubuntu.com I've received similar result:

```
You have searched for packages that names contain qtoctave in suite(s) wily, all sections, and all architectures.
Sorry, your search gave no results
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details can be found in [the publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtoctave/+publishinghistory) on Launchpad:

> Removal requested on 2015-07-28.
>   Deleted on 2015-07-28 by Colin Watson
>   (From Debian) ROM; dead upstream; superseded by GUI in Octave 4.0; Debian [bug #793459](http://bugs.debian.org/793459)

A bit more detail in the Debian bug report:

> Please remove the qtoctave package from unstable. It is dead upstream,
>   and is now superseded by the native GUI available in Octave 4.0 (which
>   has been uploaded to unstable).

As for the new GUI, see [the Octave FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Why_did_you_create_yet_another_GUI_instead_of_making_one_that_already_exists_better.3F):

> Yes! It was officially released with Octave 4.0.0. It was also
>   available since version 3.8.0 has an experimental feature (use the
>   --force-gui option to start Octave).
>
> ---
>
> QtOctave was a great and very useful tool. It looked beautiful and we
>   are thankful to its developers for working on such a nice tool.
>   However, it would have never been stable as it was. But most of all,
>   the developers made it free software so we could reuse large chunks of
>   it which were incorporated in what is now the Octave GUI.

Comment: Yes, indeed. After I've struggled searching for qtoctave and gave up, I just installed the octave package. And voila, it has now a GUI by default. To run the octave in terminal, as it was before this default GUI, we have to type `octave-cli`.